# Reactive form date picker in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have using date pickr in reactive form

[date picker ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker#usage)

The example is in template driven form..am using reactive form.

Is some one using reactive form date picker ..How to do that? Please let me know i need (only display DD-MM-YYYY) and send date to server ...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `ion-datetime` framework date picker instead of native date picker. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime   . You can get value using `formControlName`. No need to add method to ts if you don't want to modify the date picker options.Just simply can get value using formcontrol.

**Html**

```
    <ion-item class="">
      <ion-label class="" position="floating">Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime formControlName="datePckr" value="{{modifyDate}}"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

**Ts**

```
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";
```

...

```
currentDate: any;
```

...

```
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe,) {
    this.currentDate = new Date();
    this.modifyDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.currentDate, "y-M-d");
  }
```

If you want realtime check the value, then add `(ngModelChange)="func($event)"` Need to send $event every time.

**Html**

```
    <ion-item class="">
      <ion-label class="" position="floating">Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime formControlName="datePckr" value="" 
      (ngModelChange)="checkVal($event)></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

**Ts**

```
    checkVal(eve: any) {
       console.log(eve);   //write here what you want
    }
```

Comment: I need initial set today and max date also today date..pls let me knw how to do that?

Comment: ok you need to edit question like that. I will add my update to that.